# My Intent UI Extension are not displayed when i ask to siri

Tags: swift, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I have written a Siri Intents extension with a corresponding `IntentsUI` extension. But only the custom intent response is sayed by siri, the `IntentsUI` is not displayed.

All targets `.plist` have my CustomIntent in the `NSExtensionAttributes` `IntentsSupported` array.

The `IntentUI` is displayed when i open the lockscreen siri suggestion notification, but not when i ask to siri

I tried to add os.log in `IntentViewController` `configureView()` function but nothing displayed in the console when i ask to siri

Siri : https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MayS.jpg 
Siri Suggestion: https://giphy.com/gifs/W3NNEuRIwrpbiAR0tb

```
func configureView(for parameters: Set<INParameter>, of interaction: INInteraction, interactiveBehavior: INUIInteractiveBehavior, context: INUIHostedViewContext, completion: @escaping (Bool, Set<INParameter>, CGSize) -> Void) {
        guard interaction.intent is GreenGroceryIntent else {
            completion(false, Set(), .zero)
            return
        }

        let width = self.extensionContext?.hostedViewMaximumAllowedSize.width ?? 320
        let desiredSize = CGSize(width: width, height: 300)

        completion(true, parameters, desiredSize)
}
```

```
extension IntentViewController: INUIHostedViewSiriProviding {
    var displaysMessage: Bool {
        return true
    }

    var displaysMap: Bool {
        return false
    }

    var displaysPaymentTransaction: Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

What are the steps to make the custom UI to show, what can I check to make sure I have done this correctly ?

Thanks.

Comment: welcome to SO! Provide some code for your question: what you tried, etc See also  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue. I worked on some siri shortcut myself a month back. I tested it again last Aug 13 and it didn't work. Specifically my custom intents does not trigger the extension UI view controller.

I stumbled upon this tweet and was able to confirm my suspicion that there was an issue in apples side.
https://twitter.com/joehribar/status/1162036267682394112?s=20

They mentioned it works well in ios 13. Its a pain however to develop for ios 13 coz you have to update OS, Xcode and the phone to beta.

Other thing I could think of is to create a build and install it on your ios 13 phone so you don't have to update your OS and Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marianne, that's confirm my test. Yesterday i try in iOS 13 yesterday and UI appear correctly.

Comment: Siri Shortcuts UI are back https://twitter.com/joehribar/status/1162778128122441728